# How am I computing e^x incorrectly?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to estimate `e^x` using the power series for approximation in Haskell.

```
import Data.Function

-- Take two integers and divide them and return a float as a result.
-- So 1/2 would be 0.5
fd :: Int -> Int -> Double
fd = (/) `on` fromIntegral

-- Helper function to compute factorial
fact :: Int -> Int
fact 1 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n-1)

-- Calculate e^x using the power series for e^x (n is the number of
-- of terms used to approximate e^x
computeHelper :: Double -> Int -> Double -> Double
computeHelper x 0 res = res + 1
computeHelper x n res = computeHelper x (n-1) (res + (x**n `fd` (fact n)))

compute :: Double -> Int -> Double
compute x n = computeHelper x n 0.0
```

Calling `compute 1 5` gives `6`. Which is incorrect.

Both `fd` and `fact` appear to be working fine. Therefore, I'm guessing the issue is with `computeHelper`. However, following the same logic in Python:

```
from math import factorial

def compute(x, n, res=0):
    if n == 0:
        return res + 1
    return compute(x, n-1, res + (x**n*1.0/(factorial(n))))

print compute(1, 5)
```

I get `2.71666666667` which is as expected, so I am confused why the Haskell version doesn't work.

Comment: The factorial one-liner that doesn't leak space when appropriately typed (unlike your implementation) is `fact n = product [1..n]`. There are, however, much faster multi-line definitions.

Comment: You should also define your factorial for 0. 0!=1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its an operator precedence issue. The `fd` has a higher precedence than the `**`. If you add extra parenthesis its clearer why you are getting a 6:

```
(x**(n `fd` (fact n)))
```

The way to fix this would be to put parenthesis around the exponentiation and then tweak things a bit so they typecheck:

```
((x^n) / (fromIntegral (fact n)))
```